# Watermark application

Tags: c#, .net, watermark

I am creating an Application which will create a watermark effect in windows. For example whatever window a user will open, a watermarked picture will be shown to him in this form. 
I have set the window state to *Maximized* and *Opacity* to **20%** and *FormBorder* style to **None** and with this settings i get the perfect watermark effect.

But now here comes the problem: i cannot use the Components of whatever window on the back, until i close my application.

Is it possible to disable the input capturing for my application at all such that it will be in front, but all input will be directed to the window which is in back?

Comment: Put some code to understand your problem better

Comment: Thank You Guys the above mentioned link solved my problem